How to add Mail.Send permission when creating application with secret?
I'm trying to automate the process of creating an Azure AD application using Azure PowerShell. Specifically, I want to create an application, add a client secret, grant the Mail.Send permission, and generate a token, all within a single PowerShell script. However, I’m encountering a few challenges.
I was able to create the application successfully and add a client secret. However, I'm unsure how to add the Mail.Send Application permission to the application. I found the permission ID but don't know the correct command to implement it.
Once the permission is added, do I need to grant admin consent explicitly, or is that handled automatically? I want to ensure everything is set up correctly before generating the token.
Here’s the code I’m working with:
Connect-AzAccount

$appName = "MyTestingApp"
$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName -IdentifierUris "https://myapp.com"

$secret = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(1)

$permissionId = "a0e0c2c0-6b4c-4c98-bcd8-15e7995d8f2b"  # Mail.Send permission ID

$tenantId = "xxxxxxx"
$clientId = $app.ApplicationId
$clientSecret = $secret.SecretText
$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenUrl -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
$token = $response.access_token


Hi @user12072310 Any update?

Yes @Sridevi it worked perfectly __ could you share code for delegated token with username as well?

Please post a new question with more details on your new requirement and share the link here

here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79162045/how-to-generate-a-delegated-token-with-username-and-password-in-azure-ad-using-p

Are you okay with using Azure CLI command in middle of PowerShell script for granting admin consent?

yes, pls go ahead

You can make use of below sample PowerShell script to add Mail.Send permission when creating application with secret and generate token:
Connect-AzAccount

$appName = "MyTestingApp"
$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName

$secret = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $app.AppId -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(1)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

$graphApiId = '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
$mailSendId = 'b633e1c5-b582-4048-a93e-9f11b44c7e96'

$graphSp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$graphApiId'"

Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId $app.Id -ApiId $graphApiId -PermissionId $mailSendId -Type Role

$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.AppId

New-AzADServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $sp.Id -ResourceId $graphSp.Id -AppRoleId $mailSendId

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

$tenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id
$clientId = $app.AppId
$clientSecret = $secret.SecretText

$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenUrl -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
$token = $response.access_token

$token

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where new application with secret and permission added successfully with admin consent as below:

When I decoded the generated token in jwt.ms website, it has Mail.Send permission in roles claim like this:


Connect to Azure Account
Connect-AzAccount
Create the Azure AD application
$appName = "MyTestingApp"
$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName -IdentifierUris "https://myapp.com"
Add a client secret
$secret = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(1)
Define the permission ID for Mail.Send
$permissionId = "a0e0c2c0-6b4c-4c98-bcd8-15e7995d8f2b"  # Mail.Send permission ID
Add the Mail.Send permission to the application
$resourceId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000

Thanks, but it did n't help—could you share what you changed from my original code?
