How to generate a delegated token with username and password in Azure AD using PowerShell?
I'm automating the creation of Azure AD applications using PowerShell and running into an issue when trying to generate a delegated token. I've been able to create an application, add a client secret, and even generate a token using client credentials (app token) with no issues.
The token works fine for app-level permissions. However, I'm not sure how to modify my script to add delegated permission and generate delegated token that can act on behalf of a user.
Here’s the code I’ve been using for generating the client credentials token:
Connect-AzAccount

$appName = "MyTestingApp"
$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName

$secret = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $app.AppId -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(1)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

$graphApiId = '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
$mailSendId = 'b633e1c5-b582-4048-a93e-9f11b44c7e96'

$graphSp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$graphApiId'"

Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId $app.Id -ApiId $graphApiId -PermissionId $mailSendId -Type Role

$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.AppId

New-AzADServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $sp.Id -ResourceId $graphSp.Id -AppRoleId $mailSendId

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

$tenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id
$clientId = $app.AppId
$clientSecret = $secret.SecretText

$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenUrl -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
$token = $response.access_token
$token

Everything works fine here for client credentials, but I’m stuck when it comes to delegated tokens. Any guidance on how I can adjust the script to generate a delegated token with Mail.Send permission using username would be really helpful.

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to add Mail.Send delegated permission and generate token using username password flow in PowerShell?

Initially, you can run below PowerShell script to create an application with secret and add Mail.Send Delegated permission with consent:
$appName = "MyTestingApp0611"
$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName

$secret = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $app.AppId -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(1)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

$graphApiId = '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
$mailSendId = 'e383f46e-2787-4529-855e-0e479a3ffac0'

$graphSp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$graphApiId'"

Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId $app.Id -ApiId $graphApiId -PermissionId $mailSendId

az ad app permission admin-consent --id $app.AppId 

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

When I ran above code, new app registration created successfully having Mail.Send Delegated permission with consent like this:

To generate a delegated token with Mail.Send permission using username password flow, refer below sample script:
$tenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id
$clientId = $app.AppId
$clientSecret = $secret.SecretText
$username = "sri@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "xxxxxxxxxx"

$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send"
    username      = $username
    password      = $password
    grant_type    = "password"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenUrl -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body

$token = $response.access_token
$token

Response:

To confirm that, I decoded above token in jwt.ms website and got scp claim like this:


It worked perfectly __ thanks a lot!
